# Is it correct to say, "they charge expensive amount of money?"

Tags: sentence-choice

If it is not correct, does it atleast get the meaning across for a native speaker?

Comment: **A considerable amount of money** sounds correct to me.(**expensive amount of money**, I dont think, is correct or that much idiomatic.)

Answer (score 4):

**Expensive** means 'costing a lot of money'; it describes the thing being bought, not the amount paid for it. Your sentence would 'get the meaning across', but would show you up as a poor speaker of English.